# Dynamically updated favicon not working in Firefox bookmarks

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, firefox

I'm building a website that sets the favicon for itself after loading its config from a rest API. The config contains the favicon src URL.

If I hardcode the favicon in the head like this, it works:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://my-favicon-storage.com/favicon.png">
```

[image]

But if I dynamically update like this, it doesn't work:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

const faviconLink = document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']");
faviconLink.href = customFaviconSrc; // https://my-favicon-storage.com/favicon.png - url from the config loaded from rest API
```

[image]

How can I make this dynamically set favicon work in bookmarks for Firefox??

Comment: You can report that issue(?) on bugzilla.org  - PS: if you use `faviconLink.setAttribute("href", customFaviconSrc);` at least the initial favicon is presented in bookmarks.